# PHP memory limit is not being added osx

Tags: php, apache, osx-lion

I am running on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4,

i have php running and in /etc/php.ini i have set the memory limit to be 1024M

```
; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 1024M
```

now when i run a script it gives me this error

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 474610 bytes) in

this looks like PHP has only 256 mega bytes of memory allocated, so where is the rest of the memory i am asking it to allocate ?

I am out of ideas to solve this here

Comment: have you restarted the apache server

Comment: yes, I did, am using sudo apachectl restart

Comment: @nivanka - do you have any code to show us? It might be a coding issue rather then a memory-limit-setting issue.

Comment: It seems that only 25M (26843545/(1024*1024)) have been allocated not 256M.

Comment: i am using silverstripe CMS, and the 2.4.5 version. and the action i am going to perform is /dev/build. the problem is i am not sure which bit is using a lot of memory. but there are no ini_set usage to set the memory limit in the run time.

Comment: Have you looked for other PHP configuration files located elsewhere?

Comment: no, if i run php --ini this is what i get $ php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /private/etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

Comment: No that it will solve any insane desire of using 1 gig of ram per php process. But all you shall need is 128M max at most. 48M being the Silverstripe requirement. Any PHP script requiring more than 256MB should be send back to the programmer with a slap on the wrist. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience in using silverstripe CMS, but I found this:
http://www.silverstripe.org/general-questions/show/16355 and http://www.silverstripe.org/installing-silverstripe/show/20228

Maybe it can help you in right direction.

Another clue? (about php.ini)
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2446810?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: thanks, I came across those two really before posting the question, am having this problem in my localhost, which is a OSX machine. but this is strange when i run a file with phpinfo(); in there it gives me 1024 as the memory limit. but when running the CMS it gives that errors

Comment: In Windows php.ini could be at several places on the hard-drive. Maybe something similar with Mac? Are you sure then that you have changed the correct php.ini ?

Comment: i got it solve, in the codebase there was a ini_set thanks for all your help

Answer (score 1):

set your memory limit to -1

```
memory_limit = -1
```

Comment: I think chandresh_cool meant `memory_limit = - 1`
(http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit)

Comment: @ThierryMarianne that is true

Comment: @nivanka if you set it to -1 it will not give you the allowed memory size problem as we are not forcing the memory limit using this

Comment: did u restart your apache?

Answer (score 1):

When I get errors that don't seem to match behavioral expectations of php.ini settings, the second thing I do (the first thing, restarting the server, was already mentioned) is check that I edited the correct php.ini file. Try using phpinfo() in a page really quick to make ensure that the php.ini file you're editing is indeed the one being used according to the settings.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your web server is loading the corect php.ini file. You can check that by  preparing a test php file with the following function call at the very beginning `phpinfo()`. It's important for you to make sure that the field `Loaded Configuration File` is the exact same as the path to the file you are editing.

Also, if you try to take a shortcut here and attempt to read the value of the mentioned configuration option from the PHP CLI you might run yourself into additional trouble. In many operating systems PHP CLI and PHP interpreter used by the local web server are using different configuration files. This means that output from `phpinfo()` run in PHP CLI might be different than when invoked through the web server.

Answer (score 0):

You can run php without memory limit. The command in terminal is: php -d memory_limit=-1
Symfony gives following solution: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors